# Interface for PHP app in Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a pure, working, PHP application with its own specific and complicated MSSQL database.

In Rails, I want to receive data from this app without any SQL adapters, because it's too complicated to run queries directly from Rails.

For example, there is a `getCustomersWithAccounts` method it PHP database that returns array of clients. How can I get this array from my Rails app?

Maybe use the PHP-CLI and run `/usr/bin/php5 get_customers.php`, which will print the JSON array. But how to implement this from Rails?

Now I use shared memcached keys.

Comment: Do you know about [find_by_sql](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-find_by_sql) ? If you don't like it, just build some HTTP REST API in PHP returning JSON and fetch it via [Active Resource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) in rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution of using shared memcached keys is one way to go to transport data from one to the other.

Another solution that might give you some more flexibility would be having the Rails app query the PHP app over HTTP. Basically you would be building a webservice API for yourself, you could return JSON or XML, or whatever format is most useful to the Rails app.